# Freebase Twitter Extension

Tags: twitter, freebase, mql

I have tried the Freebase MQL twitter search extension shown here:

http://www.freebase.com/docs/mql_extensions/.base.topics.news.twitter_mentions

and there appears to be an error. There is no documentation for this extension (at least I didn't find it). Could anyone tell me if there is?

Does anyone know if any of these extensions are being supported at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is broken right now and I don't have time to debug. You should not depend on these extensions working on top of mql going forward, but at the same time copying the code and trying it by yourself is very easy in Acre - just sign-in and clone this app:

http://www.freebase.com/appeditor#!path=//mqlnews.masouras.user.dev/twitter_mentions

Sorry for the unsatisfactory answer, let me know if you need help using Freebase or Acre, or join freebase-discuss@googlegroups.com and post questions to that community too.